# Stored procedure takes time on database server using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

When I run the stored procedure on the local machine's SQL Server, it takes 2 seconds, but on the database server, it takes 10 seconds.

For both, local and database server, the execution plan is the same.

How do I find out the reason for taking too much time to execute the stored procedure?

Thanks.
[ExecutionPlan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hMhj.png)

Comment: Well let's have a look at the plans, https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: I would use sp_whoisactive to inspect it while it's running. Confirm you have the same indexes. Confirm it isn't a network issue (is it a large dataset?) Do both machines have the same resources (CPU, RAM?) Do both databases have the same size tables?

Comment: Same plan, same options? [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Maybe you have an index in the local DB that does not exist on the server?

Comment: Do you have the same data on both servers ?, It may well take 2 seconds to run over 1,000 records while taking much longer to run over 1,000,000 records.

Comment: And the resultset of a local database query does not travel over a network to get from the database engine to your application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.